# Python socket: Decoding packets issue

Tags: python, sockets, security, byte, sniffing

Im trying to decode sniffed packets to plain data but im encountering problems while trying,

My code:

```
import socket

HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)

sock.bind((HOST, 0))

sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)


sock.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)


while 1:
    packet = sock.recvfrom(65565)
    print(packet) # Sniffed packet
```

Sample of sniffed packet:

```
b'E\x00\x00($\x84@\x00\x80\x06\xa5\x80\xc0\xa8\x01\x07\xb9\x19\xb6\x02\xe7O\x00P\xbf\xd2\xe3R\xb0=:\xf6P\x10\x80\x00\x89\x0f\x00\x00'
```

Another one:

```
b'E\x00\x05P!D@\x00w\x06\xac\x98\xb9\x19\xb6\x02\xc0\xa8\x01\x07\x00P\xe7O\xb0=5\xce\xbf\xd2\xe3RP\x10\x7f\xf5:\x92\x00\x00P\x8c\xa3^6]\xb2c\xcdJ5\x1e>\xc0Xos\xf2\xd25o\xbf\x8b\xaa\xdb\xe0r\x16\xa1\xa5\x01O\xea+\x9a\xbe\xd8%D\x03?\xb6\x92\xed\x10\xe9\xa1/\xa4\xfb\x1f@\x9b\xc6Z\xf4\x1d\xfb\xa9\x06L\xa7\x01s\x8c\xe66\xbe\x03\xa2oS\xba\x92w\t\x05\xc0N\x1f\x0c\x80\xa2\xd2\x0e\xaa\x82BD\xdf\x8f=\xea\x1cf\xe7}x\x0f\xa0\xfe\xa0*\xd2i\x10\xbe1\xa0\x1e\x12\xc0Q\x85%\x84\x05\x8e;\x1f[\xeb\xcbbK\xb2\x8c\xa2\xfe\xc8\xe8\xc0\xc2g\xbd;\xddT\x9d\xd9\r]\x89\x11f\x8e\xc6\xb5\xa4\xb7\xf1\x05e\x81\xf2\xa2\x96\xca\x10\xdcQ\xb6\xf4\r\xc1\x9c<@l\xdf2\x94l\x13\x95\x98\x19\xa6h\xbc\xf5\xd4S\x97&^\x10\xa0\x91\x12\xc4\x11B\xd8A\x84\xb2\t\xf3\x18OhYb\xc3%t\x8cL /\x17\xad\xdfF\xeb\x0f\xf6s\xf0\x12\xdc-\xd9\x80\xcb\xa8\xe2\x1a\x97\xff\xcb\xbfPU\xe0\xdf\x89]\x9e\x00\xcbj\xee]\x97\xef\xe5:j\x1e"\xcbee\xf9\x90o\x83*\x11"-\xc1\xd9\x81\x0e@cbmu/\xba\x88\xfd\xbc\x87\xfaQ\x85\xe5\xe4\x15\x86\'n-\xe2wHzU\x80\xfd5\x9c\xeaQQx\x02|\xac\xad\xb9R \xc0\xc4\xefQi7Sg8_|\xdfF\x8d\xd9\xe4\xf3TN\xfe#\x8b\xf5\x1a\x99R)\xcc!;j\xc6Gt\x0cOyI\xa2\xca\x00\x19a\x82@\xf6\n\x11w,{U\xbc\x05]G@\x80NT\xb8X\xa4\xf4X\xde#W\x98\xc2@M\xb8a\x84^\xe7\x04\xf7x\xfa\\\xda\xa4\x1d\xec\xc8R\\\x12\xfc\xda\xa2\x9b\xcb\x8a\xe0(\xfb\xb3\x83\x12\xea\x88\x1f4\xed\xbb\xfd\xfe\x96MM\xde0k\xb3\x85\xf7\xc3kS\xc4_\xb9X\x93t\x83!\xc4\xd6\xa1\x14\x05f\xa3\xa1p\xe4\x13W\x13\x84\xcd\xdf\xa0U\x15\x028\x1d\xde\xb3V\xaf\x19\x1c\x1c\xec\xb2/\xa2EW\xda\x83\x87\x99K\xb8\xbe\xf1W\x83\xec\x9c\xd8\xf4\x17\x0e\x97\xb9\xa8\xa8\xac\xe8\x83]:\xe5G\x88p\xe5\x10\x8c]\xc8\x91\xf6\x98\xb6\xe6\xcaLe}\x0ec\xe5\xd2#\x13\xbaT}\xef\x02\xe1</\x1e\xdfC>\xf8\xc0\xd3<sI\x87\xe78\x8b\x1ff\x8b;\x00\xa82\xea\x8b\x18\x94\xeeUM\x07z\xd6?\x9cC\\\xa7\xd3uL\x8e\x04\xfa\xb1\x85PS<tt\x16\'\xbb=\xd5$X]i\x9f\xaf\xb3\xbb&^\x95#_3>\xc5\x9f\xe5r\xa6q\x02\xee\x15\x929g\x13\xb5\x1d\xe8\xdfq\x89d9\xc6\xea\x81\xb922\xd0\xd9\xeb\xd5\xaa0\xed\xd9\x8fh\xb0\x95\xd3\x9b\xed\rp\xab\x9aJ\x8a9b\xfc\xd7M\xc4\xc2[\xfc)\n\xee\x17\xe89\xcd\xbb-\xff}Yc<\x8d\xcf\x10\x17<\xecEw\x04\xadDy,W\x87\xf8!\x94/\x90M5\xd3\x82\x11H\xe1\x08\xa0x\x1b\x8b!\xde\x15\xd6\xd0ABRF\xa6?qfO"\x13\xa1\xc1\xfd\xd3\xf2\x91\xda\xad\x07\xd3\x170\x8a\x9d{\x8b\xb65\xd1\xdc\xd3\xe6\x84\xa6y\xb7\x92Y\xc5J\xeb;\n\x1c\'\xb0\x07\x87 \xfcv\x92\xab\xd6\x9dP\xaast~;\x1a\x189^\xa4\x0f\x874\x14=E\xc0>\xe9@&\xf7/\xec+<\xe2\xf0\x9cz<r\xb8\x9c\xba\x8e3Q\xd8U\xc7\xc2\xe7\x06\xe9,uj\x8fY9\x16\xad\xbf\x15q\x83\x91\xf2z\xf8\xbf#8\x046a\x89\xc8\xcb?\xfc\x86xV\xa4\xbdQ\x02U\xb8\x10\xe7%\x1d\x98\x16\x0cz,nH\xf9\xb3\x1b\xad?\xc0K\x848\xc2\x00\xbe7\xc4\xb3\x85:Eb\x0c\xa6\x00U\xb8\xae\x0c\xfe\xfd\xfd\x1eX\x1e=\x85PHR\x0bL\xfe}\x8fY\xc8\xd3\x02\xc8g\xf7C%d\xd4:u\xd6\x9d\xaf\x16\x05\xe4\x82\x80\xc0_\x9f\xd3\xb4\xcd\xf94\xd8\xcd\'\xaaM\xe2\xa9\x1c\xfb\xcd\xc3\xa4\xcbZR\xf1X0g\xfb\x9eJl\x86+\xd6ypuF\xbc\xa1\xeb\xde\x00\xa3!\r\x1c\xc8\x1c.=\xedE4\xa1\x0e,\xf9\x1e\xab\xf9\x80\x82u\x83\x9f\xe6\x00\x9c\xfb\xe0\xcb\x02\xe20B\xe4\xb8o<j\x8fh\r\x10\xf7\t\x07ooB\x84\x89Z\xc7\xb1f\xfe\xfd\xd9\xf9\xa0\xecBZ\xa4\xbe\x82Au\x0cxt\xc4D\xa0\xbbB"\xd0!\xaa\xf4\x1f\xb3-\xe2q\x0e\xce\x998\xcd\xe1\xd2\x97\x9c\xd9\\x\xcc[*\xdd\x1c\xf5w1\xe5 \x16d&\xc0\xb1|\xe82\xfd\xad\xdf>b\x07\xdb\x89k\xb5\x03)\xa4\xf7\xa3\xcc\xed\xdf5\x19v\x024\xa9\xf7\xf1\xad\x14\xbf\xf9\x85\xfcL\x96\x839L\x1f\x1c\x9a\x1ce\x00\xaf/\xc2\x8e2\xc5 ]\xbd\x0e\xfcTn%\x1c\'\x88\xa7\xae\x9a\x1e#4\x89\xc7"0O\xfd\x95\xab\xd3\xd2\xc7\xca\x1c\xbe\xa7c\x95\x10\x12\xf5\x02y\x02\x13\xa8\xf2\x9d|X\xfe\xe2\xf1\xf6\x91\x16\x8bN\xffp\xba\x1c\x0b]\x08=\xe0\xd0\x07\xa5\xc7\x15\xf1\xe8Q\x82O\xfc\xa0\x08I\\\xdei\xe45\x90g\'\x02\xdc(:\xdb\x8c:\x9eU\xac\\wy\xe9\x8e\xda\xa1}a\x1dD\xdb\x1c\xca^\xa0Q\x0f\xc3\xd9q\x1c\xd4\\\xdd\xc0[\x1b\xcc\x9fH\n\xb1Y>\xf8\x17\xd1W\xe3\xd5\xee\xef?\xa8\xb4\xaei\xb8ko\xd8\xd7"o\xfe0\x9f\x8c~\xd7\xe0\xaaS"W\x90\xf9\x82\x18\xc4\xdc\xba\xa0\xcdR\xff\x88 \xc4e\xca7q\xef\xd5\xe7\x87\x0fnW\xc6\xe2r\xc5Si\xc0\x13
```

I tried `data.decode('utf-8')` as suggested in some threads but it seem to not work

Please help ! It will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm assuming you meant decode vs decrypt. You need to know what data is being sent and how it is encoded. Are you sure there it is encoded and not just binary data?

Comment: @AChampion Its not possible to decode it??

Comment: That depends on if it has been encoded or if it is binary date.

Comment: @AChampion If its binary, how can it be decoded and if not how?? please help me sir?? do i have to use chr/ord here??

Comment: If it is binary you will need to know what protocol/format, e.g. if it is truly encrypted you will need to know the key and the decryption routine. If it is just `encoded` data you need to know the encoding... I cannot help you beyond that.

Comment: pleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaase help me guys !! networking experts, python experts where are you !!!!!!!